# problem with pagination in custom permalinks

Tags: permalinks, pagination

I have set custom permalinks:
/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

When I use the following url: http://revelutions.com/sandbox/one/2013/08/30/
works fine. However, when I click on the second page, I get a 404

I have tried this on a clean site.

This also occurs with a standard theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: Use the Category Pagination Fix plugin

Here is the reference: http://www.jonoalderson.com/blog-updates/permalinks-category-pagination/ (lengthy explanation)